# boost::filesystem:path detect that two paths share same physical drive

Tags: c++, boost, boost-filesystem

### Background

I have some complex application which can consume lots of disc space (~10TB). To prevent unheated errors which comes from disc full scenarios my application has some logic which mages stored data.

Currently runs on Windows platform, but it is ported to Linux.

### Problem

It is possible that two kinds of data are stored on different physical drive. Depending on that business logic is a bit different. Now on Windows physical drive can be identified by `boost::filesystem::path::root_path()` (it is not perfect, but good enough in my scenarios), but on other platforms this logic falls apart, since `root_path()` is always `empty()`.

### Question

I'm looking for some multi-platform solution (boost preferably) to detect if two paths are sharing same physical drive.
If there is not such thing I will have to use platform specific API and I prefer to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is taking a step back and rethink your approach:

If your OS and file system support it, try [creating a hard link](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#create_hard_link). Now you know relatively reliably whether they are the same file system. (Unfortunately, using network file systems and the like one can still avoid the OS knowing the file systems are really the same.)

Knowing whether it is the same hard drive finally seems rather pointless for preventing stuffing too much crap onto it, even if it is interesting for throughput, and probably needs OS specific handling.

And if you know the paths should be the same, creating a test file lets you avoid any kind of flawed simulation and just let the system figure it out for you.

Comment: Looks like you misunderstood question. I have two different unrelated paths. One is some my application cached files other is database location (I can detect that it is on different machine). My aim is to manage disc space. If disk space is running low some features are disabled (to prevent system wide errors) and user is warned that he should clean some data. When database and my cache files are on different drives logic looks a bit different.

Comment: @MarekR Deemphasized equivalent path, emphasized only same filesystem, kept note that same hard drive seems uninteresting in the situaton and needs OS specific handling anyway to determine.